# finish() не срабатывает при быстром переключении активити

Tags: android, activity

Помогите разобраться, почему не срабатывает finish() при быстром переключении активити. Если переключать с интервалом, то по кнопке back выходит в главное меню и оттуда можно закрыть приложение, а если быстро попереключать активити, то при нажатии на кнопку back открывается главное меню, но при нажатии на back, чтобы выйти, снова открываются предыдущие активити.

Так делаю для кнопок вперед/назад:

```
public void right (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Colors.this, Colors2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.leftr, R.anim.rightr);
    finish();
}

public void left (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Colors.this, Pets.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left, R.anim.right);
    finish();
}

// выход в главное меню
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Colors.this, Stage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Потому что `startActivity(intent);` без специальных настроек (атрибутов в манифесте или флагов в интенте) не возвращает в существующую, а запускает новую копию активности в верхушке стека. Почитайте этот урок: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/190-urok-116-povedenie-activity-v-task-intent-flagi-launchmode-affinity.html - там довольно подробно разбирается поведение активностей в таске

Comment: @woesss, спасибо за статью. Очень полезная информация.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне встречались несколько способов решения такой проблемы, и, к сожалению, иногда не срабатывает ни один.

1. `YourActivity.this.finish();` вместо `finish();` Где `YourActivity` - класс завершающейся активности
2. `((Activity) this).finish();` опять же вместо `finish();`
3. Создать отдельный метод в своей `Activity`:

   ```
   public void killSelf() {
       this.finish();
   }
   ```

   И вызывать его вместо `finish();`
4. Для **API >= 21** можно вызвать другой метод:

   ```
   finishAndRemoveTask();
   ```
5. Если Вы передаете какие-то данные через `Intent`, то нужно помнить, что объем передаваемых данных не должен превышать *1 Мб* в соответствии с документацией. С учетом хранения служебной информации - лучше не выходить за пределы *500Кб*.
6. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

   ```
   startActivity(intent
       .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
       .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
   );
   ```

   С такими флагами `finish();` будет не нужен, однако уничтожены будут вообще все экраны кроме вызываемого!

Comment: Как и выше был добавлен комментарий про использование TASK-ов, пункт 6 решил данную проблему.